# sudo apt update - 404 Not Found [IP: 138.199.37.226 443]

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

I get the below error after I run `sudo apt update`

How can I fix this?

```
Hit:1 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://mirror.hetzner.de/ubuntu/packages focal-security InRelease
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/nginx-mainline/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Ign:12 https://packages.sury.org/nginx-mainline focal InRelease
Err:13 https://packages.sury.org/nginx-mainline focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 138.199.37.226 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://packages.sury.org/nginx-mainline focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: If you go and look, that *repository* doesn't provide support for any Ubuntu releases; it's for Debian systems.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks, I tried the above link and the solutions provided there did not work. How can I remove it? I changed the sources.list links but that did not help.

Comment: You've provided no details as to what type of system (desktop, server), but I'd just use `vi` to remove it myself.  More details can be obtained at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  (*or the server docs, but you've not provided product specifics*)

Comment: You are right. I use Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS focal.

Comment: I *guessed* that from the *focal* in your pastes; but as I said; you've not said if it was a Desktop system (*where my wiki link matches perfectly*) or Server system where it still applies; but it's done slightly differently & screenshots showing GUI don't help; thus you can use the server docs version I mentioned but didn't provide link for; some result & change just different UI tools being used.